# Extracting text between 2 Patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have text somewhat similar to below:

```
Random text 
"XXX" some text "XXX" 
1. random text 
2. Random Text
3. Random text
"YYY"
Random Text
```

I wanted to extract eveything that appears between "XXX" (including) which is at start of the line and "YYYY" (Excluding) which is also at the start of the line
"XXX" if present will be present in the beginning of the line
Note that "XXX" can appear many times in between text
"YYY" is not fixed , i.e. "YYY" can have any value. I just need to identify pattern where some word(S) appears between " & ".

expected result:

```
"XXX" some text "XXX" 
1. random text 
2. Random Text
3. Random text
```

I tried below regex, but unable to extract completely:

```
re.findall(r"^\"XXX\"(.*?)\s^\"w+\", string, re.DOTALL)
```

```
Random text
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for

```
^("XXX".+?)^"YYY"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xk7iFZ/1/) (and mind the `dotall` modifier).